# Expectation of maximum of two positive independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $\xi,\eta$ be two positive independent random variables with known expectations. Can I use them somehow to bound the expectation of $\max(\xi, \eta)$?

The motivation is: if I know the Wasserstien distances for $\mu, \mu'$ and $\nu, \nu'$ can I used them to find a bound on the distance between $\mu\otimes \nu$ and $\mu'\otimes\nu'$? Here $\xi$ ($\eta$) would be distributed according to the optimal coupling for $\mu$ and $\mu'$ ($\nu$ and $\nu'$).

See also a [related question on MO.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/232121/11768)

Answer (score 1):

If the sum is enough: for any $a,b\geq 0$, you have $\max(a,b) \leq a+b$.
So $$\mathbb{E}[\max(\xi,\eta)] \leq \mathbb{E}[\xi]+\mathbb{E}[\eta].$$

Comment: Indeed, the sum gives an estimation - I've went a long way through CDFs for that. However, is there something a bit less conservative?

Comment: There may be, not entirely sure: do you know the cdf's of the r.v.'s? Or, say, their moment-generating function? (for the latter, if you do [this (Section 2) may help](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gautamd/Files/maxGaussians.pdf).

Comment: If you know the CDF's, you can use this (but I reckon you already have considered it): for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\mathbb{P}\{\max(\xi,\eta) \leq x \}=
\mathbb{P}\{\xi \leq x \}\cap\{\eta \leq x \}
= \mathbb{P}\{\xi \leq x \}\cdot \mathbb{P}\{\eta \leq x \}
$$
so
$$
\mathbb{E}[\max(\xi,\eta)] = \int_{0}^\infty (1-\mathbb{P}\{\max(\xi,\eta) \leq x \}) dx
= 
\int_{0}^\infty (1-\mathbb{P}\{\xi \leq x \}\cdot \mathbb{P}\{\eta \leq x \}) dx
$$

Comment: Based on the motivation, I only know the W distances, hence only the expected values, and I can't really assume any other info regarding the distribution.